# Applications works while debugging, but doesn't work when "released"

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

So, I just made a standard, `QtQuick 2` application, it has the default `Recangle`, `Text` and `MouseArea`. So, I just tried to compile the application in release mode, to see what files it would generate, and then I tried opening the application and this happened:

[image]

When I resize it, I cans see white space:

[image]

However it all works fine in debugging:

[image]

I am using Qt 5.0.1 and QtQuick2

### Update

So, after running it through [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) it appears like there are three files missing: `qt5quick.dll`, `qt5gui.dll`, and `qt5core.dll`. **Do I have to manually add them from somewhere?**

The current directory structure is:

```
`test-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MSVC2010_32bit-Release/release
|+qml
 |+test
  |-main.qml
|-main.obj
|-moc_qtquick2applicationviewer.cpp
|-moc_qtquick2applicationviewer.obj
|-qtquick2applicationviewer.obj
|-test.exe
|-test.exe.embed.manifest
```

Note: I pasted the qml directory as suggested in [Nemanja Boric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14812814/553801) from the parent directory, but that didn't solve the problem! :(

Also, I was under the impression that none of the source (apart from JavaScript maybe) wouldn't be *openly* distributed with the app, but compiled or packed inside the application somehow (note the `.cpp` file and the `qml` directory)?

### Update 2

The application works just fine when run from inside Qt 5 Creator:

```
Starting [...]\test-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MSVC2010_32bit-Release\release\test.exe...
QOpenGLShader::link: "(41,18): warning X3206: implicit truncation of vector type

" 
[...]\test-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MSVC2010_32bit-Release\release\test.exe exited with code 0
```

Well, apart from that one awkward warning...

Comment: There's probably some uninitialised variable or buffer overflow.  If you're using Linux, get valgrind on it.

Comment: Is problem the same when you run test.exe, or does it now reports missing dll issues?

Comment: @NemanjaBoric No, it actually just *launches* and looks like the second image. This make no sense...

Comment: Are you sure you are running correct version (I assume you are, but I see executable file named differently than manifest file, so maybe it is some old file?)

Comment: Oh **facepalm** No, I was reading about some ancient chat thing called "thepalace" and just typed it out without thinking, lol. It's actually `test.exe.embed.manifest`

Comment: Ok - so just one more try, as I don't know what else can be wrong: Do you have in your main.cpp file something like: `setMainQmlFile("qml/test/main.qml");`? Does it work, or is there any error messages in application output when you run Release version in creator with CTRL-R?

Comment: @NemanjaBoric Oh, blimey, it works when I run it inside Qt. And, the line of code you pasted, looks like: `viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/test/main.qml"));` in my `main.cpp`, but that's the same gist, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy qml files into your current directory. When you create release application with QtCreator, you will have this directory structure (or something like this):

```
example-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MSVC2010_32bit-Release
  |-     debug
  |-     qml
  |-     release // application executable is here
```

What you need to do is to copy `qml` folder to be in the same directory with your executable release file (simply copy `qml` folder into `release` folder).

About dll files - you can copy them manually from `QtInstallDir/bin` folder or you can add that directory into `PATH`, if you are developing on that machine - it could be easier.

You don't need to publish cpp files, but you need to publish qml files. What you can do, through I never succeed, but it seems to be possible is to bundle qml files into Resource file, and to load it from resources, but that can be extracted easily, too - so - **don't put your logic or confidential informations in qml files**.

Also, you need to copy all required dll files into directory with exe: qt5quick.dll, qt5gui.dll, qt5core.dll and libEGL.dll.

Comment: Ah, that did absolutely nothing. :(

Comment: @starship How are you running program? It is working here fine. Don't copy contents of the qml folder, but the folder itself, and run exe file from release directory.

Comment: I had to copy `libEGL.dll` into the folder, too. It wasn't mentioned by Dependency Walker, though. So, I guess just add that to your answer so I can accept it! :D

Comment: @starship I will, great :).